# Increasing update rate of CMPedometer

Tags: ios, core-motion

I'm building a pace/cadence tracker app and I'm thinking of using the `CMPedometer` type.

My initial investigations are that `CMPedometer` gives updates at a rate of once every 2.8 seconds.

Is there a way to increase the update rate of `CMPedometer`? If not, what other type of pace / cadence tracking is available to us?

Comment: See also [CMPedometer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmpedometer/) and this [tutorial](https://makeapppie.com/2017/02/14/introducing-core-motion-make-a-pedometer/)